# Can't Add Reference to My WCF Data Service

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service. I can browse to it OK in my browser and I can make queries to it successfully via the URL...but I can't add a Service Reference to it, and I can't add it to OData Explorer...it just throws an error

> The document at the url
>   http://localhost/Services/OData/Repository/
>   was not recognized as a known document
>   type.

When I browse to my service at `http://localhost/Services/OData/Repository/`, I see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="http://localhost/Services/OData/Repository/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
    <collection href="Contacts">
      <atom:title>Contacts</atom:title>
    </collection>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

Which is exactly what I would expect and want. And if I go to `http://localhost/Services/OData/Repository/Contacts`, I get my results of Contacts returned successfully.

I suspect this has to do with how I'm adding my OData service, but I'm not sure. I don't have an svc file. Instead I'm adding a route to my RouteTable as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Services/OData/Repository", 
                                       new DataServiceHostFactory(), 
                                       typeof(IMyRepository));
```

I do have a clientaccesspolicy.xml file, but that shouldn't matter since this is localhost...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding a service reference, what you want is the the $metadata end point:

http://localhost/Services/OData/Repository/$metadata

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently upgraded to another version of Windows?

If so, you need to run

```
ServiceModelReg -i
```

You can find that in your %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\Windows Communication Foundation folder.

Comment: No...and adding references to other odata sources like services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/ works.